# what is the solution for show different pop up with same button?

Tags: button, popup, oracle-adf

i have a choice list with different action (add file or add comment) and a button OK. 
The button will show pop up according to action select. My question is how i do this in same button?

I create two pop up's but i don't know how to invoke them after.

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could change the text on the button per pop up window. Then when the button is clicked, pick your pop up based off of the text on the button. For example, initial state of the button says open, then when its clicked you display a pop up and change the button text to close. Then when the button is clicked again you close the window and change the button text to open.